# What does it mean when an async method uses time on a thread?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx):

> The async and await keywords don't cause additional threads to be
>   created. Async methods don't require multithreading because an async
>   method doesn't run on its own thread. The method runs on the current
>   synchronization context and uses time on the thread only when the
>   method is active.

My takeaway from the "async and await keywords don't cause additional threads to be created" is that it simply uses threads already created from the thread pool, which is fine, but the bit I have trouble understanding is "uses time on the thread when the method is active".

Does this mean that when I am awaiting the task, the task "moves" to the current thread or are the results marshalled back to the current thread? If you look at the output, the results come back on a different thread ID but complete on the original thread after they are all complete. I think I'm missing the "in between" of these two operations.

```
void Main()
{   
    var tasks = new List<Task<byte[]>>();

    Console.WriteLine ("Starting on Managed Thread ID {0}, Background {1}, Pool {2}\n", 
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground,
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(WriteFile(@"D:\Temp\" + i + ".txt", new String('*', i)));
    }

    Console.WriteLine ("Before Wait()ing on Managed Thread ID {0}, Background {1}, Pool {2}", 
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground,
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread);

    Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait();

    Console.WriteLine ("Completed on Managed Thread ID {0}, Background {1}, Pool {2}", 
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground,
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread);
}

async Task<byte[]> WriteFile(string path, string text)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

    try
    {   
        Console.WriteLine ("Writing to file " + path + " . Managed Thread ID {0}, Background {1}, Pool {2}", 
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground,
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread);

        var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);

        await fs.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        Console.WriteLine ("Finished writing to file " + path  + ". Managed Thread ID {0}, Background {1}, Pool {2}", 
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground,
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread);

        return new byte[0];
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Finally! " + path + ". Managed Thread ID {0}, Background {1}, Pool {2}\n", 
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground,
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread);

        fs.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Starting on Managed Thread ID 46, Background True, Pool False

Writing to file D:\Temp\0.txt . Managed Thread ID 46, Background True, Pool False
Finished writing to file D:\Temp\0.txt. Managed Thread ID 12, Background True, Pool True
Finally! D:\Temp\0.txt. Managed Thread ID 12, Background True, Pool True

Writing to file D:\Temp\1.txt . Managed Thread ID 46, Background True, Pool False
Finished writing to file D:\Temp\1.txt. Managed Thread ID 12, Background True, Pool True
Finally! D:\Temp\1.txt. Managed Thread ID 12, Background True, Pool True

Writing to file D:\Temp\2.txt . Managed Thread ID 46, Background True, Pool False
Finished writing to file D:\Temp\2.txt. Managed Thread ID 12, Background True, Pool True
Finally! D:\Temp\2.txt. Managed Thread ID 12, Background True, Pool True

Writing to file D:\Temp\3.txt . Managed Thread ID 46, Background True, Pool False
Finished writing to file D:\Temp\3.txt. Managed Thread ID 24, Background True, Pool True
Finally! D:\Temp\3.txt. Managed Thread ID 24, Background True, Pool True

Writing to file D:\Temp\4.txt . Managed Thread ID 46, Background True, Pool False
Before Wait()ing on Managed Thread ID 46, Background True, Pool False
Finished writing to file D:\Temp\4.txt. Managed Thread ID 18, Background True, Pool True
Finally! D:\Temp\4.txt. Managed Thread ID 18, Background True, Pool True

Completed on Managed Thread ID 46, Background True, Pool False
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My takeaway from the "async and await keywords don't cause additional threads to be created" is that it simply uses threads already created from the thread pool

No, that's not true at all. `async` and `await` don't use the thread pool at all at a language level. It's entirely possible to write a program using async/await which only uses the initial "main" thread.

That doesn't mean that everything *will* happen on a single thread - it's just that async/await don't *force* extra threads to be created. The compiler itself doesn't generate any code to do that. It's entirely up to what you're awaiting. For example, you *can* task a task using `Task.Run`, which will (usually) use the thread pool, and you can await that. Or you can await the result of calling `Task.Delay`, which in itself doesn't start any threads but just schedules the task to be completed at a future time. Or you could use asynchronous IO, which may use IO completion ports but won't actually involve another thread *running* for most of the time that the task is "active".

A well-designed awaitable (if you're using anything built-in, this will include you) will schedule the continuation (all the code after `await`) in the same context as you were in when you started awaiting it, unless you've specifically told it not to. That "context" may mean that you come back to the same thread (e.g. in a UI) but may not (e.g. in the thread pool context, it doesn't matter which thread pool thread the continuation runs on).

In my view, it's worth learning more about what async really does under the hood. There are lots of resource around this, both free and behind paywalls:

- The [Visual Studio async home page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)
- An [MSDN Magazine article by Stephen Cleary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx) with lots of details
- ["There is no thread"](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) - another Stephen Cleary blog post addressing this specific issue
- Eric Lippert's [async blog posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/async/)
- My [async blog posts](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/async/default.aspx) give a fair amount of detail, although they were mostly written during the CTP phase; the *thrust* of it is still correct, but some details have changed
- Chapter 15 of the third edition of my [C# in Depth](http://manning.com/skeet3) book is entirely about async/await
- Many Pluralsight courses on C# 5 will talk a lot about async; I have a course *just* about async which you may be interested in if you have a subscription

Comment: So in other words, if I await a task which wasn't designed to run on a separate thread that the entire operation will run synchronously?

Comment: I am slowly going through those blogs. Perhaps I should read them all before posting any further questions. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @VincePanuccio: It's not about awaiting it - it's about the task itself. Awaiting just waits for the task to finish and then returns to the current context.

Comment: So the implementation of the task is what defines the surrounding codes ability to run asynchronously or synchronously ?

Comment: @VincePanuccio: *Sort* of. If the `Task` somehow forces itself to run on a particular thread, that's clearly going to affect your ability to run on the same thread... but I don't think I'd express it the way you have. I suspect that more reading will help you :)

Comment: I also have a [blog post specifically answering the "where's the thread?" question for asynchronous I/O](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Comment: @JonSkeet a lot of those examples talk about what happens when you `await` an async method. What happens if you do not `await` it? Surely then it 'runs' on another thread, yes? One thread must do some work while the async method goes off and does other work, with the main thread not awaiting the results of the async method. Is that correct? So not awaiting is equivalent to doing `Task.Run(AsyncMethod)`?

Comment: @Jamie: It runs when it needs to - but a lot of the time there could be *no* threads running, with the system just passively waiting for something (e.g. a network response) to happen. Asynchrony isn't the same as just running code on another thread.